# WebAssembly + WebView + Javascript Interface for heavy calculations?

Tags: android, ios, webassembly

So I'm working on this app which currently are written natively for the web, android and ios. This app does some heavy lifting in the background which we are looking for ways to improve, but keeping three sources of basically the same code sucks.

One way is to make a library in C++ which is then used in the apps and through WebAssembly on the web. This however requires us to generate new versions of the android/apps and publish them to their respective stores.

But then I thought that WebAssembly might be usable on all platforms. But since we still want to offer a native experience on the mobile platforms I'm thinking that a WebView could be used to with a javascript interface to communicate with the library in WebAssembly and present the data natively. Updates to the library would only have to be done once and all apps always has the latest version of the library.

Would this be possible and would it still offer high performance? Would the webview and javascript interface be bottlenecks?

Comment: "But then I thought that WebAssembly might be usable on all platforms" - why would you do that? C++ runs natively on iOS and Android. You'd only need to compile to WebAssembly for the web.

Comment: @ColinE I know, but: "This however requires us to generate new versions of the android/apps and publish them to their respective stores." Meaning I would like to skip the part of updating the apps each time that library is updated.

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand you have a native Web App (HTML + JavaScript) and native Android (Java or Kotlin) and iOS (Swift or Objective-C) apps. The app does some heavy lifting that has performance issues - I am guessing that these issues only arise in the web (i.e. JavaScript) version of the app? You want to improve the performance of this code, and also share it across all three platforms?

If that is the case, I think WebAssembly is worth considering. You can create a library in C++ which is run natively in iOS and Android, and compiled to WebAssembly via EmScripten to run on the web.

One things to bear in mind is that WebAssembly has no built-in IO. Therefore all interactions with your code would have to cross the JavaScript / WebAssembly boundary, which does incur a penalty. Therefore, this approach works best for algorithms that have a simple interface, e.g. they might perform a lot of calculations on a small amount of data, then return the result.

I am not sure why you are considering running this in a WebView? For iOS and Android you will not need to use WebAssembly - you can run the C++ code natively.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this, but if there is still high performance while using WebAssembly in the android/ios apps then I get the benefit of not needing to update them each time the library is updated as its loaded in a webview. If this reduces performance significantly then running the C++ library natively is obviously the way to go.

Comment: Android is not such a pain in the ass to update if a quick fix is needed as it only takes a few hours to get the update available to everyone through the play store. 
iOS updates through the App Store has gotten a LOT better lately, but there is still the chance of it taking a lot longer.

Answer (score -6):

Depending on what your C++ library does, it might be just impossible.

Opposed to what Web"Assembly" sounds, ***WebAssembly in browsers is basically a JavaScript***, as it is run and managed by a JS engine. Wasm runs in the JS context offered by WebView. So it is not correct WebView can be used to interface between JS and Wasm. The correct way to say is that the JS also runs Wasm.

This has a huge implication: **Wasm does not have access to native APIs**, but JS APIs. If your C++ code needs native Android services such as file assess, you are not supposed to use Wasm.

In terms of performance, it also depends on what your C++ code does. The performance benefits of Wasm achieved by not running JS Garbage Collection, not by running natively. Wasm currently cannot run GPU, SIMD, or multithreading (though these features will land in the future, but not there yet).

The biggest point of WebAssembly is porting C++/Rust/Go/etc codes to web browsers, not necessary to increase performance.

There are [some efforts to run Wasm in native platforms](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/03/standardizing-wasi-a-webassembly-system-interface/) outside of JS engine but they are not mature yet, and it is very far from running in native mobile platforms.

Comment: "WebAssembly in browsers is basically a JavaScript" - incorrect - WebAssembly is a different language that runs in its own virtual machine. "The performance benefits of Wasm achieved by not running JS Garbage Collection, not by running natively" - not strictly true, WebAssembly performance gains are primarily because it removes the complex parse / optimise / re-optimise that JavaScript suffers from.

Comment: "WebAssembly (abbreviated Wasm) is a binary instruction format for a stack-based virtual machine" - WebAssembly.org. Wasm can interop with JS, but it is not JS. You should correct the false stmts here to improve your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @BumsikKim, Wasm does not run in the JS context, it's just it can interoperate with JavaScript, but that's a different thing. Yet WebAssembly isn't the same as normal Assembly languages (it's still going to run on top of a virtual machine), it's way more efficient than JavaScript for a lot of different reasons: not only it doesn't use garbage collection, but WebAssembly is lower–level (which means less abstraction from the VM), it gives access to fixed–size types (thus allowing programmers more proficient than you to fine–tune their code), and will only result in slower code if misused.